# Query from SQL Server tables in Oracle using ODI

Tags: sql-server, oracle, oracle-data-integrator

I have a database in Oracle and a database in SQL Server.

I want to write a query in Oracle and I need to use one of SQL Serever table in it.

Before I used database link but now I must to do this with ODI (Oracle Data Integrator).

The way I used before:

```
      CREATE PUBLIC DATABASE LINK "DBLINK"
       CONNECT TO "MatrisApp" IDENTIFIED BY VALUES ':1'
       USING 'dg4msql';



INSERT

    INTO everyday_deposit_temp ***/*this is a table in oracle*/***
      (
        "DEP_ID",
        "REF_DEPOSIT_TYPE",
        "REF_DEPOSIT_SUB_TYPE",
        "LEDGER_CODE_SELF"

)
    SELECT "DEP_ID",
      "REF_DEPOSIT_TYPE",
      "REF_DEPOSIT_SUB_TYPE",
      "LEDGER_CODE_SELF"

    FROM dbo.vw_deposit_changed@dblink
```

Please help me with this

Answer (score 0):

The most common way to get data from MS SQL Server to Oracle through ODI is to use [LKM MSSQL to ORACLE (BCP SQLLDR)](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/odi/develop-connectivity-km/ms_sqlserver.htm#ODIKM957).

Now if you really want to use a dblink, I would try this approach:

1. Duplicate a Oracle IKM you want to use
2. In the definition tab, check the Multi-Connections checkbox and set Microsoft SQL Server for the Source Technology.
3. In the Options tab, add a new option DBLINK_NAME with Value type.
4. In the Tasks tab, find the task responsible of the insert and edit the target command to add this after the table name : `@<%=odiRef.getOption("DBLINK_NAME")%>`
5. Create a mapping using the new IKM. In the Physical tab, click on the target table and add the dblink name in the Option.